# Fill in missing values in a Matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix pulling from a table with incomplete data. A record is created when the value changes. If the value stays the same between years, there's no record. If a given year is newer than the change year, I want the value of the column to be the last valid entry for that item.

Rows is Item No

Column is Year

Value is a measure that's supposed to fill in Empty Values:

```
Latest Lead Time =
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(MAX('lead time history'[Year]))
RETURN
    IF(
        ISBLANK(MAX('lead time history'[Clean New Lead Time])),
        CALCULATE(
            LASTNONBLANK('lead time history'[Clean New Lead Time], 0),
            FILTER(
                ALL('lead time history'),
                'lead time history'[item no] = SELECTEDVALUE('lead time history'[item no]) &&
                'lead time history'[Year] <= CurrentYear
            )
        ),
        MAX('lead time history'[Clean New Lead Time])
    )
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image: tnewhook_1-1687300812848.png]

Lead Time History table:

[image: tnewhook_2-1687300914741.png]

A sample PBIX is at [CalculatedMatrix.pbix](https://file.io/TRi74GFH7MlZ)